# Clickable setIcon()/setLogo() in default action bar

Tags: android, kotlin, appbar

I have default action bar with home buttom, logo/icon, title

[image]

I need make logo/icon (not home buttom) or title clickable (clickListener)

How to make it in default action bar?

Comment: Define a custom toolbar and include the ImageView inside it. Then from the respective activity / fragment reference to it and set a clicklistener.

Comment: yes, i know that, but i need default action bar for default back buttom for animation and navigationView

Comment: You can still use it as the default one. Just use the noactionbar theme in your styles.xml as parent theme for your app and set the navigationview up with your custom toolbar